# batch files: show all hidden files; define if a file has an attribute or not

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, hidden

I am trying to make a program which allows user to add/remove hidden or read-only attributes to a file and to see all hidden files in a directory. Now, i have two questions:

1. How to define wether a file already has an attribute or not? I tried something like this:

   IF EXIST %file% /A:H GOTO ....

(i want to know if a file already has an attribute of "hidden")
but it doesn't work.

1. How to find out if there at least one hidden file in a directory? I tried this:

   IF EXIST *.* /A:H-D-S GOTO ...

(a file that is hidden, not a directory and not a system file)

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: `if` does not support such syntax.This is a `dir` stuff

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /ah "%file%" 2^>nul') do (
    echo file %%~F is hidden
     rem <do something with the file>
)
```

check for hidden files in dir:

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-dh-s  2^>nul') do (
    echo dir %%~F contains hidden files
     rem <do something with the dir>
     goto :break_for
)
:break_for
```

Comment: The IF statement is not needed. The DIR /B /AH command will only list hidden files. If there aren't any, then the loop will be empty, so the IF will never be reached.

Comment: first example is ok, it works, but speaking about the second one - i don't need to search for a hidden dir. i need to find out if there are ANY files in a dir, that are hidden (attributes: H, -S and -D)

Comment: The IF statement is needed if the argument to DIR is a file that may not exist. In the case of the file not being there, you'll get a return of "File Not Found" which will falsely trigger the DO block.